# How to delete whole directory with files in it using Django default_storage

Tags: python-3.x, django, minio, django-storage

My Storage Structure:

```
my-bucket/

    - dir_1/
        - file_1
        - dir_A

    - dir_2/
```

What I tried:

```
default_storage.exists(name='dir_2/')

o/p:  True


default_storage.delete(name='dir_2/')
```

`dir_2` got deleted successfully.

But when I try the same for `dir_1`:

```
default_storage.exists(name='dir_1/')

o/p:  False


default_storage.delete(name='dir_1/')
```

This doesn't work. **dir_1** still exists

How to delete **dir_1** completely using the `default_storage`?

Answer (score 0):

I used bash scripts to delete the folders and then called the scripts from Django. You could obviously use powershell scripts or vbscript if you were on windows.

I realise your question involves default_storage but this is a work around. The other option would be looping through the directories and deleting the files individually and then deleting the empty folder.